# Finding and replacing text in HTML not doing anything

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I want to find and replace specific words in a text area using user-specified keywords.

This is what my HTML document looks like:

```
Message: </br>
    <textarea name="text" id="message" rows="3" col="20">Hello 202109</textarea> </br></br>
    Find: <input type="text" name="find" id="find" size="15"> Replace: <input type="text" name="replace" id="replace" size="15"> <br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="findAndReplace()">Find and Replace</button> <br/>
```

And I'm using this for my Javascript function:

```
function findAndReplace() {

let find = document.getElementById("find").innerHTML;
let replace = document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML;
let text = document.getElementById("message").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = text.replace(find, replace);

}
```

However, when I open my webpage and try clicking on the "Find and Replace" button nothing happens and no text gets replaced. Inspecting the webpage also shows no errors whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution to your problem :)

```js
function findAndReplace() {

let find = document.getElementById("find").value;
let replace = document.getElementById("replace").value;
let text = document.getElementById("message").value;
document.getElementById("message").value = text.replace(find, replace);

}
```

```html
<textarea name="text" id="message" rows="3" col="20">Hello 202109</textarea> </br></br>
Find: <input type="text" name="find" id="find" size="15"> Replace: <input type="text" name="replace" id="replace" size="15"> <br />
<button type="button" onclick="findAndReplace()">Find and Replace</button> <br />
```

There is also this interesting guide:
https://superuser.com/questions/1037389/innerhtml-vs-value-when-and-why

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`. `.innerHTML` gets the inner markup of the element, and can't be used on inputs and textareas. `.value` is the property you're looking for.

Comment: Ah I see, that explains everything. Thanks!